# Point domains to springboot app. running in different ports inside a ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, dns, routes

I have 2 hosted zone defined in route53: domain1.com, domain2.com, and 2 springBoot app running inside a ec2 instance but in different ports.
I would like to know if it is possible to point domain1.com to app1 and domain2.com to app2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You have two options:  one using a classic load balancer, the other using the Application Load balancer.

You would need two classic load balancers, one for each domain.  Then you would associate the appropriate listener / port to each load balancer.

With the Application load balancer, you have the option of doing host-based routing, so you would only need one.  You would have two target groups, one for each instance/port combination.